# Discord.py looping a song after it finishes

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, youtube-dl

So initially I was trying to make a loop command that loops once the song **finishes** however this only loops after a minute or a minute and a half instead of waiting until the song is finished.

````
@client.command() 
@commands.is_owner()
async def loop(ctx):
    vc = ctx.voice_client
    current_song = queuee[ctx.guild.id][0]
    song_name = songs[ctx.guild.id][0]

    guild_id = ctx.guild.id
    if guild_id not in loop_status:
        loop_status[guild_id] = False

    if not loop_status[guild_id]:
        loop_status[guild_id] = True
        await ctx.send("Looping current song.")
        loop = True
        

    else:
        loop_status[guild_id] = False
        loop = False

        await ctx.send("Unlooping current song.")
    ```
async def check_queue(ctx):
    global loop
    if ctx.voice_client.is_connected():
        if queuee[ctx.guild.id]:
            if not ctx.voice_client.is_playing():
                if loop == False:
                    queuee[ctx.guild.id].pop(0)
                    songs[ctx.guild.id].pop(0)
                    vc = ctx.voice_client
                    player = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(queuee[ctx.guild.id][0], **ffmpeg_options)
                    vc.play(player) 
                    return
                else:
                    vc = ctx.voice_client
                    player = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(queuee[ctx.guild.id][0], **ffmpeg_options)
                    vc.play(player)
                    return
        else:
            await asyncio.sleep(30)
            await vc.disconnect()
    else:
        return
````

The function `check_queue` is responsible for playing the next song in queue or looping the current song if the `loop` variable is `True`.

Also one thing to note, For some reason once you loop a song you can't unloop it because I get the errors

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 409, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/container/main.py", line 1414, in on_command_error
    raise error
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 190, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/container/main.py", line 570, in loop
    current_song = queuee[ctx.guild.id][0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

```
[tls @ 0x564839bd9b40] Error in the pull function.
[matroska,webm @ 0x564839bd6900] Read error
[tls @ 0x564839bd9b40] The specified session has been invalidated for some reason.
    Last message repeated 1 times
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a lot to unpack here.

First off, you've created a dictionary, `loop_status`, which looks like the right way to go, except you're also using a variable, `loop`, which by the looks of it would change the value for looping for *all* of the guilds which I can't imagine is the intention. Either way it isn't declared as a global variable in the loop command so it does literally nothing. Not to mention that it shares the same name as the async function `loop`, which should be avoided.

I also can't see how looping and then unlooping would cause an error as `queuee` isn't modified at any point during looping or unlooping, unless you're doing something else in the interim.

I can then only assume that you start with `loop` is being set to `False` globally, then the command loop is called, but the variable `loop`'s value is unchanged since it isn't global. After that, `check_queue` is being called and the original `False` value is being used for loop, which means that it pops the first (and would have to be the only) item in `queuee[ctx.guild.id]`. This then means it wouldn't actually loop, and then the loop command is used again to unloop, but the first item has now been removed from `queuee[ctx.guild.id]` so an index error is raised.

You're going to need to fix the loop value (probably better to use the `loop_status` dictionary) before you can fix the looping problem, I can't offer a solution as it looks like there are other more immediate problems in your code.